# Ein Gespräch halten / führen / haben Unterschied?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Ich möchte wissen, was der Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Sätzen ist:

> Wir haben ein Gespräch gehalten

> Wir haben ein Gespräch geführt

> Wir hatten ein Gespräch [über...]

Edit: Ich habe auch den Fall mit dem Verb "haben" in die Frage hinzugefügt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gespräche werden *geführt*.

Man kann zwar viele Dinge halten (von Gegenständen bis Reden), aber Gespräche gehören nicht dazu. Das wäre nicht idiomatisch.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit "ein Gespräch haben"? Kann das richtig sein? Es klingt für mich vlt. umgangsprachlicher bzw. nicht so gehoben wit mit _führen_.

Comment: *Ein Gespräch haben* geht. *Ein Gespräch führen* ist ganz normales Deutsch und überhaupt nicht gehoben.

Comment: @Olafant vielleicht individuell, aber ich würde „ein Gespräch haben“ nicht benutzen. Und ich bin Muttersprachler.

Comment: @Stephie *Ich hatte gestern ein Gespräch mit Frau Maier.* ist m.E. ein ganz normaler Satz.

Comment: @Olafant vielleicht regionale Unterschiede. Und wie gesagt - nicht Teil meines aktiven Wortschatzes.

Answer (score -1):

> ein Gespräch in Gang/am Laufen halten

ein Gespräch welches über einen längeren Zeitraum geführt wird (z.B Chat) und das man weiterführen/fortführen will

> ein Gespräch führen

ein Gespräch mit einem/mehreren Gesprächspartner führen

Comment: Ich würde die Wendungen tauschen, da die mit *führen* für die Definition der Wendung mit *halten* verwendet wird. Zudem ist die Definition der Wendung mit *führen* tautologisch (sie wird mithilfe von sich selbst definiert); sie sollte daher umgeschrieben werden.